# Why wait() in consumer not able to get notification from producer notifyall()?

Tags: java

Following is my code

```
public class Factory {

    static boolean iteminfactory = false;
    public synchronized void producer(int i ) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Producer started " + iteminfactory);
        if (iteminfactory) {
            wait();
        }

        System.out.println("Produced " + i);
        iteminfactory = true;
        notifyAll();
        System.out.println("Producer ended " + iteminfactory);
    }

public synchronized void consumer() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Consume started " + iteminfactory);
        if (!iteminfactory) {
            wait();   //  problem , not able to get notification from producer
        }

        System.out.println("Consumed");
        iteminfactory = false;
        notifyAll();
        System.out.println("Consumer ended " + iteminfactory);
    }

}

// producer
package com.example.suri;

public class Producer implements Runnable{
    static Factory f;

    public Producer () {
        f = new Factory();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; ++i) {
        try {
            f.producer(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
}

//consumer

public class Consumer implements Runnable {
static Factory f;

    public Consumer() {
        f = new Factory();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; ++i) {
            try {
                f.consumer();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

// main

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Producer p = new Producer();
        Consumer c = new Consumer();

        Thread tp = new Thread(p);
        Thread tc = new Thread(c);

        tp.start();
        tc.start();
    }

output

Producer started false
Consume started false
Produced 0
Producer ended true
Producer started true
```

wait inside consumer function is not getting notification from producer.Why is it so?
If I create single instance for Factory and shared with both consumer and producer , everything working fine. i.e changing constructor like this.

```
Producer(Factory fact) {
f = fact;
}
Consumer (Factory fact) {
f = fact;
}

// Main
Factory f = new Factory();
Producer p = new Producer(f);
Consumer c = new Consumer(f);
```

But my question is why notifyall() differentiating between instance of factories as it should only notify threads which are waiting

Comment: I'd suggest putting the `wait`s in loops rather than `if`s. E.g. `while(iteminfactory) { wait() ; }`.

Answer (score 2):

wait/notify/notifyAll api's tries to obtain mutex on enclosing instance. So if you are waiting on notification from object1, then only object1 can notify rather than object2.

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) for details.

```
The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes execution.
```

In Factory you are synchronizing on this object i.e. on a particular instance. And in your producer and consumer class, you are instantiating factory so you have two different instances and hence you are synchronizing on two different instances.

I would suggest, you inject factory via constructor so that both producer and consumer use same factory instance and hence let to synchronize on common factory object.

Comment: Just a minor point: `wait` etc. act on the recipient object, not the enclosing instance. When no recipient is specified, the message is sent to `this`, just like any other message. Nothing prevents one from writing `foo.wait()`.

Comment: No that's not true. You have to enclose object (which you want to access mutex on) in synchronized block everytime else you are going to get IllegalMonitorStateException.

Comment: What is true is that the thread that sends `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` must hold the lock of the recipient object. The usual way to ensure this is to place the call directly within a synchronized method and not use an implicit recipient. But this is not the only way. For example, the following command can occur anywhere you like; it does not need to be within any particular class: `synchronized(foo){foo.wait();}`.

Comment: Correction to previous comment: "and not use an _explicit_ recipient".